# Can I run javascript synchronously from Java on Android (v2.2 and above)?

Tags: javascript, android

I'm trying to run some javascript from within my Java android app but I need it to run synchronously. WebView can't accomplish this since loadUrl and loadData don't have return types. Really, what I'm looking for is something equivalent to this on iOS's UIWebView:

```
- (NSString)stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:(NSString)script
```

I tried using Rhino but it's WAY too slow for my purposes.

Thanks!

Comment: "I'm trying to run some javascript from Java ..." technically is statement is incorrect .

Comment: i changed the wording to be more precise.

Answer (score 0):

Yes but you'll have to use [WebView.addJavaScriptInterface()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29).

Comment: That's a subset of @brindy's answer but doesn't really satisfy what I need because for my purpose because I need the entire call to be synchronous java->js->java, like stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: in iOS

Comment: There is no other API to use other than our answers.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is synchronous, however, like you correctly note, there's no way to return a value from the call.  Dan alludes to a solution ...

Firstly, create a simple class like this (assuming your return type is a String):

```
public class MyCallback {

    private String returnValue;

    public void setReturnValue(String s) {
        returnValue = s;
    }

    public String getReturnValue() {
        return returnValue;
    }

}
```

It's important to keep this class simple and encapsulated because if you're loading HTML from potentially untrustworthy sources it could present a security hole in to your application.  That is, don't be tempted to simply pass in your Activity and have the Javascript call methods on it directly.

Then execute the Javascript you want giving it an instance of the callback to store the result:

```
 WebView webView = // ... get this from somewhere
 MyCallback callback = new MyCallback();
 webView.addJavaScriptInterface(callback, "callback");
 webView.loadURL("javascript:callback.setReturnValue(someFunction())");
 System.out.println("return value is " + callback.getReturnValue());
```

Comment: This doesn't work unfortunately. loadURL isn't synchronous so the result to the callback hasn't been set when loadURL returns.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but I see there's no answer. Here's how I do it (but be careful blocking the UI thread here (Kotlin).

```
class MyWebView @JvmOverloads constructor(
  context: Context,
  attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
  defStyle: Int = 0
): WebView(context, attrs, defStyle) {

  private val lock = ReentrantLock()
  private val condition = lock.newCondition()

  private inner class MyJsInterface {
    @JavascriptInterface
    fun finished() {
      lock.withLock {
        // Do stuff (Not the UI thread)
        condition.signalAll()
      }
    }
  }

  private val jsInterface = MyJsInterface()

  fun syncJsCall(js: String) {
    lock.withLock {
      loadUrl("javascript:$js")
      condition.await()
    }
  }

  init {
    options.javascriptEnabled = true
    addJavascriptInterface(jsInterface, "MyApp")
  }
}
```

Then run something like:

```
webview.syncJsCall(
  """
    (function() {
      console.log("hello world");
      MyApp.finished();
   })()
  """.trimIndent()
)
```

Answer (score 0):

`webView.evaluateJavascript()` runs asynchronously but you can use a simple semaphore to wait for the execution.

Steps:

1. Create a javascript interface (basically a class with a method that is going to be called from the javascript we want to evaluate.

   ```
    public class MyInterface 
    {
        private String value;
        private Semaphore semaphore;

        public MyInterface(Semaphore semaphore) {
            this.semaphore = semaphore;
        }

        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        @JavascriptInterface
        public void setValue(String value) {
            this.value = value;
            //important release the semaphore after the execution
            semaphore.release();
        }
    }
   ```
2. Add the javascript interface to the Android web view

   ```
    Semaphore mySemaphore = new Semaphore(0);
    MyInterface myJsInterface = new MyInterface(mySemaphore);
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(myJsInterface, "jsInterface");
   ```
3. Execute the javascript and await the execution

   ```
    webView.evaluateJavascript("var myValue='this works';jsInterface.setValue(myValue);", null);
    //await the execution
    mySemaphore.acquire();
    //the interface now have the value after the execution
    myJsInterface.getValue();
   ```